# Excel: Check Value in a list and color it according to result

Tags: excel, list, conditional-formatting

I been looking for hours, for a way to check data from 1 table to another with conditional formatting, something like this :

[image]

And the conditional formatting would color the cell on table A if any of the items match with another from table B.

Comment: The input is a bit unclear: could you please specify from your sample which cells in A should be colored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use Conditional Formatting across worksheets (I've just realised). The only way to do it would be to have a "copy" of your lookup data on the same sheet as the cells where you want the Condintional Formatting. So set e.g. A3 = Sheet2!A3, A4 = Sheet2!A4 etc. You should then be able to use Conditional Formatting for the cells. So select one cell in table A, go to Format/Conditional Formatting and pick formula, then go for something like this:

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(D3,$A$3:$A$6,1,0)))
```

Where D3 is the cell in table A, and $A$3:$A$6 is the location of table B. Or similar.

Comment: AFAIK you *can* use conditional formatting across worksheets. The trick is to create a global Named Range, and use that instead of the direct reference.

Comment: @iDevlop. Nice one - better plan than mine actually.